# Jquery - Adding and removing items from array

Tags: arrays

I want this click event to check to see if the item is in the array. If it is, remove it. If not, add it back in the same spot.

```
var myArray = ["apple","orange","pear","grape"];

$("button").click(function(){
    if($.inArray(apple,myArray) != -1){
        myArray.push(apple,1);
    } else {
        myArray.splice(apple,1);
    }

    alert(myArray);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Stores the last removed index in an external variable.
- Changes `myArray.push("apple");` for `myArray.splice(lastRemovedIndex, 0, "apple");`
- Changes `if($.inArray(apple,myArray) != -1)` for `$.inArray("apple", myArray) == -1`.
- Removes the element using the index `myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf("apple"), 1);`.
- Don't forget the `"` around the element `apple`.
- Updates the last remove index if the element is removed.

```js
var myArray = ["apple", "orange", "pear", "grape"];

var lastRemovedIndex = -1;
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
  if ($.inArray("apple", myArray) == -1) {
    myArray.splice(lastRemovedIndex, 0, "apple");
  } else {
    var i = myArray.indexOf("apple");
    myArray.splice(i, 1);
    lastRemovedIndex = i;
  }
  alert(myArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="myBtn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: How do I get the apple to go back to the same spot in the array?

Comment: This method will work for a toggle button that act on a specific element. If the element can change you have to track every last removed index in an object `var lastRemovedIndexes = { "apple": 1, "orange": 2 };`